# Phonegapbuild updating 3.7.0 to cli-6.0.0 not work

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build, apache-cordova

Hello I have an app developed in phonegapbuild in version 3.7 and it works very well but if I upgrade to version cli-6.0.0 stops working.
this is my config is very simple.

```
 <?xml version=”1.0″ encoding=”UTF-8″ ?>
<widget xmlns = “http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets”
xmlns:gap = “http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0″
id = “com.entre5.movil”
versionCode = “10″
version = “1.0.0″>

<name>Entre app</name>

<description>
Desarrollo personalizado ph
</description>

<author href=”https://phonegapspain.com” email=”soporte@phonegapspain.com”>
crecerweb
</author>
<preference name=”phonegap-version” value=”cli-6.0.0″ />
<preference name=”fullscreen” value=”false” />
<preference name=”prerendered-icon” value=”true” />
<content src=”index.html”/>
<platform name=”android”>
<icon src=”mdpi.png” qualifier=”ldpi”/>
<icon src=”hdpi.png” qualifier=”mdpi”/>
<icon src=”xhdpi.png” qualifier=”hdpi”/>
</platform>
<access origin=”*” />
</widget>
```

index.html

```
<script src=”phonegap.js”></script>
```

but does not work and you put a plugin like geolocalitation not it works is like no load something .
If suddenly someone already solved thank the guide.

regards

Comment: Have you tried leaving the definition out? It should build to default, which is the latest stable version.

Answer (score 0):

hello already solved and what happens is that after the clip 5 version to load jquery and other external files must be taken into account.

```
<gap:plugin name=”cordova-plugin-whitelist” source=”npm” />
<access origin=”*” />
<allow-intent href=”*” />
<allow-navigation href=”*” />
```